# Firestore returns 'instance of querysnapshot' even if the collection does not exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder(
   stream: Firestore.instance.collection('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa').snapshots(),
    builder: ( context , snap){

      if(snap.data == null){
         print('A');
      }
      if(snap.data != null){
        print(snap.data);
        print('B');
      }
```

[image]

Obviously collection ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaa') does not even exists then why it is not returning null?

Comment: for some reason its behaving like that. Why not check the length or other parameters to check if its null or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying a non-existing (or empty) collection is not an error. So when there are no results, Firestore gives you an empty `QuerySnapshot`, instead of an error.

To detect if there were any results, check if the `QuerySnapshot` has any documents (FlutterFire doesn't seem to wrap the native [`QuerySnapshot.isEmpty()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#isEmpty()).

Comment: When I am trying to get the documents in that collection it is returning empty `DocumentSnapshot`. So I think it never returns null then how do I check if it is null or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "empty DocumentSnapshot" there. If you `snap.data.documents` contains any documents, that means that the collection was not empty. Firebase will not return a `DocumentSnapshot` if there are no documents.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasData` to check if there is data or not:

```
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print("a");
              } else{
                return Text("No data");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: still getting the same results. If collection does not exists then why its not returning null?

Comment: it should return no data, if u used my code what are you getting?